# how to fix the error displayed on python shell ?

Tags: python, pdf, text, arabic

i have a code that is written in PYTHON where the code allow the user to select the path of folder that contains **PDF files** and convert it to **text files**.

the system system work perfect when the content is not **ARABIC**.

## error displayed :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\test\Downloads\pdf-txt\text maker.py", line 32, in 
>       path=list[i] IndexError: list index out of range

## code:

```
import os
from os import chdir, getcwd, listdir, path
import codecs
import pyPdf
from time import strftime

def check_path(prompt):
    ''' (str) -> str
    Verifies if the provided absolute path does exist.
    '''
    abs_path = raw_input(prompt)
    while path.exists(abs_path) != True:
        print "\nThe specified path does not exist.\n"
        abs_path = raw_input(prompt)
    return abs_path    

print "\n"

folder = check_path("Provide absolute path for the folder: ")

list=[]
directory=folder
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
            t=os.path.join(directory,filename)
            list.append(t)

m=len(list)
i=0
while i<=len(list):
    path=list[i]
    head,tail=os.path.split(path)
    var="\\"

    tail=tail.replace(".pdf",".txt")
    name=head+var+tail



    content = ""
    # Load PDF into pyPDF
    ##pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(file(path, "rb"))
    pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(codecs.open(path, "rb", encoding='UTF-8'))


    # Iterate pages
    for i in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
        # Extract text from page and add to content
        content += pdf.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
    print strftime("%H:%M:%S"), " pdf  -> txt "
    f=open(name,'w')
    f.decode(content.encode('UTF-8'))
   ## f.write(content.encode("UTF-8"))
    f.write(content)
    f.close
```

Answer (score 1):

the error can probably be solved by just changing

```
while i<=len(list):
```

to:

```
while i<len(list):
```

because in python allowed indices for a list with N elements are:
0,1,...,N-1
while trying to access the element N gives an IndexError.

Comment: i fix it this line but now i got another error:
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test\Downloads\pdf-txt\text maker.py", line 33, in <module>
    path=list[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> **

Answer (score 0):

If a list's last index is `n`, then the len of the list is `n+1`.
This means that when you want to access a list, you do NOT want to access `list[length of list]` aka `n+1` as this does not exist!

I believe the only wrong line in your code is the while, it should be:

```
while i < len(list):
```

And not

```
while i <= len(list):
```

You do not want `i` to take the value `len(list)`.

Comment: i fix it this line but now i got another error:
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test\Downloads\pdf-txt\text maker.py", line 33, in <module>
    path=list[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> **

Comment: That's because you use the same variable i in the for loop inside your loop. Use a variable j in the for loop. Also you will need to increase i every time you loop otherwise it will keep doing the same thing